# Migrate Asp.Net Membership to Oauth 2

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, asp.net-membership

I have a website built from long time ago using Asp.Net Membership. Now I am trying to rewrite it on a new website but there are some functions that are not done then user have to do it in old website. Is there any way user can login one time from old website then can access both old and new website's resource?

The new one is single page app use api server support oauth2. I do it following this article: 
http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!